# Uzo de la os-tempo post «se»

Tags: verbs

Laŭ mia kompreno en la angla, kiam oni parolas pri kondiĉo kiu okazos en la estonteco kun iom da probableco, oni preskaŭ ĉiam uzas la prezencon. Ekzemple:

> If I get up early enough, I will go to the park before work.

Mi legis ke estas [simila regulo en la franca](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-1517.php), ekz:

> Si je reçois une contravention pour excès de vitesse, ma prime d'assurance augmentera.

Tamen, ĉi tiu regulo ŝajnas mallogika al mi, ĉar la kondiĉo ja okazos en la estonteco se ĝi okazos. Do mi demandas min kiun tempon oni devus uzi en esperanto. Ĉu la as-tempon aŭ la os-tempon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In more formal English you could use *should* which is a form of future subjunctive. To some speakers it indicates the thought that the outcome is less likely.

- If you should see John, tell him he owes me money.

En Esperanto oni uzas la logikan tempon. Do -os en tiu okazo.

- Mi, subskribita, promesas ellerni la proponitan de d-ro Esperanto lingvon internacian, **se estos montrita**, ke dek milionoj personoj donis publike tian saman promeson.

Pri estontaj se-frazoj ankaŭ eblas uzi -us, se la okazo estas malverŝajna aŭ se temas pri peto.

- Se mi iam **devus** elekti fianĉinon, tiam la elekto pli volonte falus sur vin,”
- Laŭ mia opinio estus tre utile, **se vi eldonus** ĝin ankaŭ en Esperanto